# how to get mongoengine object id in flask program

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

i am using mongoengine to integrate with flask , i wanted to know how to get document object id every time i try i get `File "/var/www/flask_projects/iot_mongo/app.py", line 244, in post return jsonify(user.id) AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'`

```
class Test(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('email',required=True, help='email')
        args=parser.parse_args()
        user=AdminUser.objects(email=args['email'])
        return jsonify(user.id)
api.add_resource(Test,'/test')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 4):

I've been doing this.  An example User model would be like~

```
class User(Document):
    first_name = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(required=True, max_length=50)
    username = StringField(required=True)
    password = StringField(required=True, min_length=6)

    def to_json(self):
        return {
            "_id": str(self.pk),
            "first_name": self.first_name,
            "last_name": self.last_name,
            "username": self.username,
            "password": self.password
        }
```

I convert the id to a string.  I would then get a single object with~

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
return user.to_json()
```

for a whole object, but if I just want the id I would do...

```
user.pk()
```

I created my own to_json method that converts the primary key to a string because otherwise it would return "id": ObjectID("SomeID") instead of neatly printing "id": "SomeID".
Hope this helps!
If you want to find someone by email I suggest~

```
User.objects.get(email=args['email'])
```

Comment: @ but i could't take the value of  id when i use  " return user.pk"

Comment: Have you tried converting it to a string like str(user.pk())

Comment: It's been working for me.  The problem must be in your query logic.  Make sure you're returning an object, and not a Queryset.  To retrieve one single object use DocumentModel.objects.get(parameter=blah).   A queryset will retrieve many objects in an array or something (not sure on that detail).  I suggest reading the API section of the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [the documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#), [`Document.objects`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#Document.objects) is a [`QuerySet`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet) object.

You seem to be expecting that this part of your code

```
user=AdminUser.objects(email=args['email']) # user will be a QuerySet
```

will give you a single result, which is not the case, it will give you a `QuerySet` with zero or more results. It does not have an attribute `id`, this is why you get the error message you are seeing when you try to access this attribute here:

```
return jsonify(user.id) # QuerySet does not have the attribute id
```

You need to fetch the actual result(s) you want from it, assuming you are sure your query will return a single result, or do not care that there might be more than one result and just want the first one, you probably want something along these lines:

```
user=AdminUser.objects(email=args['email']).first() # extract first result
return jsonfiy(user)
```

Alernatively, returning all results would look like this:

```
users=AdminUser.objects(email=args['email']).all() # extract all results
return jsonfiy(users)
```

Comment: still  not getting object id from the query.. i new to mongo engine